# size of derived class in virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, sizeof, virtual-inheritance, memory-layout, vptr

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ClassA
{
    protected:
       int width, height;
    public:
       void set_values(int x, int y)
       {
         width = x;
         height = y;
       }
};

class ClassB : virtual public ClassA
{
   //12(int + int + vptr)
};

class ClassC : virtual public ClassA
{
  //12(int + int + vptr)
};

class ClassD : public ClassB, public ClassC
{
};

int main()
{
  ClassA A;
  ClassB B;
  ClassC C;
  ClassD D;
  cout << "size = " << sizeof(A) << endl;
  cout << "size = " << sizeof(B) << endl;
  cout << "size = " << sizeof(C) << endl;
  cout << "size = " << sizeof(D) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

the output i got is:

```
size of ClassA = 8
size of ClassB = 12
size of ClassC = 12
size of ClassD = 16
```

In the above code why the output is 16 for ClassD. please explain me clearly how this virtual inheritance works.

Comment: This is implementation dependent. Why do you want to rely on the size to be something specific anyways? If you need size just use `sizeof` and it shall return the appropriate size whatever it maybe. Knowing this for theoretical purposes is fine but this has absolutely no practical application.

Comment: int + int + 2 * vptr?

Comment: just to understand how this virtual inheritance. according to me the size of ClassD should be 24 bytes i.e(int + int + vptr) + (int + int + vptr) = 24 bytes . so i got confused how this works so askd..

Comment: @Jon: although there are no virtual functions here, so there should be no need for any vptrs, AFAICS.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The vtable is needed in order to locate the `ClassA` subobject.

Comment: @nagaradderKantesh There is **only one `ClassA` subobject** in a `ClassD` object. This is the whole point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual inheritance means, that the virtual base classes only exist *once* instead of multiple times. That is why the 8 bytes from `ClassA` are only in `ClassD` once. Virtual inheritance itself requires a certain overhead and hence you get an additional pointer. The exact implementation and therefore the exact overhead is not specified by the C++ standard and may vary depending on the hierarchy you are creating.

Comment: "_the 12 bytes from_" Do you mean 8 bytes?

Answer (score 2):

When ClassD inherites ClassB and ClassC there will be two vptrs (one from B and one from C). This exact case is described in Scott Meyers' "More Effective C++", Item 24 (The Cost of Various Language Features).

Answer (score 0):

### Virtual base classes implementations

Virtual base classes are exactly like virtual function: their address (or relative address aka offset) is not known at compile time:

```
void f(ClassB *pb) {
    ClassA *pa = pb;
}
```

Here the compiler must compute the offset of the `ClassA` base subobject from the `ClassB` subobject (or mostly derived object). Some compiler simply have a pointer to it inside `ClassB`; others use the vtable, just like for virtual functions.

In both case the overhead in `ClassB` is one pointer.

The `ClassC` is similar, but the vptr will be point to a `ClassC` vtable, not a `ClassB` vtable.

Thus a `ClassD` object will contain (this is not an ordered list):

- a single `ClassA` subobject
- a `ClassB` subject
- a `ClassC` subject

So `ClassD` has two inherited vptr: from `ClassB` and `ClassC`. In a `ClassD` object, both vptr will point to *some* `ClassD` vtable, but the same `ClassD` vtable:

- a `ClassB` subject points to the ClassB-in-ClassD vtable, which indicates the relative position of `ClassA` base from `ClassB` base
- a `ClassC` subject points to the ClassC-in-ClassD vtable, which indicates the relative position of `ClassA` base from `ClassC` base

### Possible optimization

I guess your question is: **do we need two distinct vptr?**

Technically, it is sometimes possible to optimize the size of classes by overlaying base class subobjects. This is one of those cases where it is technically possible:

Overlaying (or unification) means that both `ClassB` and `ClassC` will share the same vptr: given `d` an instance of `ClassD`:
`&d.ClassB::vptr == &d.ClassC::vptr` so `d.ClassB::vptr == d.ClassC::vptr` but `d.ClassB::vptr == &ClassC_in_ClassD_vtable` and `d.ClassC::vptr == &ClassC_in_ClassD_vtable`, so `ClassB_in_ClassD_vtable` must be unified with `ClassC_in_ClassD_vtable`. In this particular case, both `ClassB_in_ClassD_vtable` and `ClassC_in_ClassD_vtable` are only used to describe the offset of `ClassA` subobject; if `ClassB` and `ClassC` subobjects are unified in `ClassD`, then these offsets are unified too, hence the unification of the vtables are possible.

Note that this is only possible here as there is perfect similarity. If `ClassB` and `ClassC` were modified to add even one virtual function in each, such as these virtual functions are not equivalent (hence not unifiable), the vtable unification would not be possible.

### Conclusion

This optimization is only possible in very simple cases like this one. These cases are not typical of C++ programming: people normally use virtual base classes in combination with virtual functions. Empty base class optimization is useful because many C++ idioms use base classes with no data members or virtual functions. OTOH, a tiny (one vptr) space optimization for a special use of virtual base classes does not seem useful for real world programs.